# Colorbox open 2 popup windows closing 1

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I am using ColoxBox JS with inline popups.

Here's is the colorbox [homepage](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/):

I open window 1 and inside window 1 there ws a link which opens window 2.

My problem is that when I close window 2 ...window 1 is gone.

Is there any way to keep or get window 1 back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use frame approach and load the pages in the frame and navigate between the frames only.